# How to use masks while displaying names in tables using sql fuctions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

1. if the record [name surname] it must be masked except the first two letters
2. if the record [name name surname] the second name must be masked too
3. if name and surname have only 2 letters nothing changes

Comment: By preponderance of evidence, I'm guessing this is Oracle.  However, the question is still very unclear.

Comment: 1- [name surname]   Must be masked except for two characters for the record 

2- [name name surname] The second name for the record  must also be masked.
3- if name and surname contain 2 letters It must remain the same

Comment: I agree with Gordon... I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: I guess this is an obfuscation question

Comment: I tried to write a little clearer

Comment: `SELECT
      REGEXP_REPLACE(customer_name, '(\w+)', '*', 3) "REGEXP_REPLACE"
      FROM myTable;`

Comment: You could look into the Oracle data masking pack... http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/data-masking-subsetting/overview/index.html ... which does this and a lot more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. I'm not very sure about how oracle will handle this query.

```
select concat(substr(fn,1,2),replicate("x",len(fn)-2)," ",substr(ln,1,2),replicate("x",len(ln)-2)) as CUSTOMER_NAME_SURNAME
from (select substr(CUSTOMER_NAME_SURNAME, 1, instr(CUSTOMER_NAME_SURNAME," ")) as fn, 
        substr(CUSTOMER_NAME_SURNAME, -1, instr(CUSTOMER_NAME_SURNAME," ", -1)) as ln
        from table_name)
```

Or, my best bet would be to split the names in other table and use substrings with replicate. And then concatenate the names. But that will make it confusing and more than one table, I guess.

Additionally, for the middle name, you can use

```
substr(CUSTOMER_NAME_SURNAME, instr(CUSTOMER_NAME_SURNAME," ")+1, instr(CUSTOMER_NAME_SURNAME," ",1,2)-1) as mn
```

And then use CASE WHEN with the fn, mn, and ln.

Answer (score 2):

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE and provide REGEX expression

For example : replace all characters starting from third position.

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(customer_name, '(\w+)', '*', 3) "REGEXP_REPLACE"
  FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
(INITCAP(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),1,instr(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),chr(32),1,1)-1),1,2))||
REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),1,INSTR(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),chr(32),1,1)-1),3),'(.)','*')||chr(32)||
REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),
INSTR(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),chr(32),1,1)+1,INSTR(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),chr(32),-1,1)-INSTR(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),chr(32),1,1)-1),'(.)','*'))||
initcap(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),INSTR(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),chr(32),-1,1)+1),1,2))||
REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),INSTR(TRIM(CUSTOMERNAME),chr(32),-1,1)+1),3),'(.)','*')
AS CUSTOMERNAME FROM HR.CUSTOMERS;
```